# creating instance for a class in a dll

Tags: c#, c++, dll, managed

How can I create an instance for a class in c# dll that I imported in a c++ project? I have imported the c# library to c++ by following the instructions given [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736). I can call the functions using the public interface.
[EDIT] I want to set values for the attributes of the class in c# dll through c++ and to pass it to the dll. So that I can skip so many set functions in c# dll. If I can create object for the class, I will set the values using the object and pass the object to c# dll.

Comment: And then what are you going to do after you _pass the object to c# dll_?

Comment: I will pass it to the xml serialization function. I want to set all the data in object and pass it to dll. Dll will use it for xmlserialization.

Answer (score 0):

In the link you provided, in the c++ client code description

```
// CPPClient.cpp: Defines the entry point for the console application.
// C++ client that calls a managed DLL.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "tchar.h"
// Import the type library.

#import "..\ManagedDLL\bin\Debug\ManagedDLL.tlb" raw_interfaces_only
using namespace ManagedDLL;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Initialize COM.
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    // Create the interface pointer.
    ICalculatorPtr pICalc(__uuidof(ManagedClass));

    long lResult = 0;

    // Call the Add method.
    pICalc->Add(5, 10, &lResult);

    wprintf(L"The result is %d\n", lResult);


    // Uninitialize COM.
    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

the creation of the pointer, `pICalc` is the pretty much the creation of the object of the class. Created in the line `ICalculatorPtr pICalc(__uuidof(ManagedClass));`

Comment: I have some other classes in my dll. Can I create objects for those classes? I need to access data attributes too.